# A levels Statistics 2 Poisson Why am I getting two different answers?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

Why am I getting a different answer than marking scheme in part ii?

**Question.**

Each week a sports team plays one home match and one away match.  In their home matches they score goals at a constant average rate of $2.1$ goals per match.  In their away matches they score goals at a constant average rate of $0.8$ goals per match.  You may assume that goals are scored at random times and independently of one another.

**(a)** A week is chosen at random.

**(i)** Find the probability that the team scores a total of $4$ goals in their two matches.

**My Answer:**
$H \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda = 2.1), \\ A \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda = 0.8).$
$H + A \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda = 2.9)$.
$\Pr[H + A = 4] = e^{-2.9} \frac{(2.9)^4}{4!} \approx \boxed{0.162154}.$

**(ii)** Find the probability that the team scores a total of $4$ goals, with more goals scored in the home match than in the away match.

**My Answer:**
$\Pr[H > A]\; \text{and} \; \Pr[H + A = 4] = \Pr[H - A > 0] \times 0.162154.$
$H - A \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda = 1.3)$.
$\Pr[H - A > 0] = 1 - \Pr[H - A = 0] = 1 - e^{-1.3}$.
$\Pr[H > A]; \text{and} \; \Pr[H + A = 4] = (1 - e^{-1.3})(0.162154) \approx \boxed{0.118}.$

**Marking Scheme Answer:**
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
H & A \\
\hline
0 & 4 \\
1 & 3 \\
2 & 2 \\
\boxed{3} & \boxed{1} \\
\boxed{4} & \boxed{0}
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{align}
\Pr[H = 3, A = 1] + \Pr[H = 4 , A = 0] 
&= e^{-2.1} \frac{(2.1)^3}{3!} e^{-0.8} \frac{(0.8)^1}{1!} + e^{-2.1} \frac{(2.1)^4}{4!} e^{-0.8} \\
&\approx \boxed{0.1125}.
\end{align}$$

[Original image for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FobY6.jpg)

Comment: I typeset your question for you.  If you wish to ask questions on this site, please use my edits to learn how to do this.

Comment: Will try next time In Sha Allah, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first reason why your approach is incorrect is because $H-A$ is not Poisson distributed.  The sum of independent Poisson random variables is Poisson, but the difference is not.  For instance, if $H < A$, how could $H - A$ still be Poisson with nonnegative support?

The second reason is that the events $H > A$ and $H + A = 4$ are not necessarily independent; thus the joint probability is not the product of their individual probabilities.  With a computer, we can compute $$\Pr[H > A] = \sum_{a=0}^\infty \Pr[H > A \mid A = a]\Pr[A = a] = \sum_{a=0}^\infty \sum_{h=a+1}^\infty \Pr[H = h]\Pr[A = a] \approx 0.67437854965.$$  But we can see that $(0.674378)(0.162154) = 0.109353 \ne 0.11253$; this confirms that they are not independent events.

Comment: Ohhhh, thanks a lot! Understood the first point, but not the second point. Are you saying that P(A n B) = P(A) * P(B) is only valid if A and B are independent? If they are dependent, then this formula doesn't apply, then which one does?

Comment: @MohammadAbdullah correct; $\Pr[A \cap B] = \Pr[A]\Pr[B]$ is only true if $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  If they are dependent, then there is no such formula for the joint probability, because you would need to describe *how* they are dependent.

Comment: Understood, thanks!